# Error calling iter().sum(): the trait bound `f64: std::iter::Sum<&std::vec::Vec<f64>>` is not satisfied

Tags: rust, rayon

I am struggling with a function that is supposed to return either an `f64` or an `Error`. I have tried many combinations, but no success.

```
fn_rayon_parallel(&self) -> Result<f64, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>>  {

    let all_payoffs = (0..10000).into_par_iter().map( 
        |_| {   //things could go very wrong here        
                match self.get_one_payoff() {
                    Ok(payoff) => {Ok(payoff)},
                    Err(e) => Err(e)
                }
            }
    ).collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>();

    //this is the part I am struggling with, does not compile
    //I need to return either f64 or Error

    match all_payoffs {
        Ok(_v) => Ok(2.34 * (1.0/10000.0) * (all_payoffs.iter().sum::<f64>())),
        Err(e) => Err(From::from("There was an error in calculating Discounted Payoffs."))
    }


}
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `f64: std::iter::Sum<&std::vec::Vec<f64>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:81:69
   |
81 |             Ok(_v) => Ok(2.34 * (1.0/10000.0) * (all_payoffs.iter().sum::<f64>())),
   |                                                                     ^^^ the trait `std::iter::Sum<&std::vec::Vec<f64>>` is not implemented for `f64`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <f64 as std::iter::Sum<&'a f64>>
             <f64 as std::iter::Sum>
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28d325ae926d36dcd50f526f7d2d2ffd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem lies here (simplified a bit):

```
match all_payoffs {
    Ok(_v) => Ok(1.0 * (all_payoffs.iter().sum::<f64>())),
    Err(e) => { /*...*/ }
}
```

Note that your `all_payoffs` variable is of type `Result<Vec<f64>, Box<dyn Error + Send>>`. So when you do the `.iter()` you think that you are getting an iterator for the values of the vector, of type `&f64`, but you are instead getting an [iterator for the ok-value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/result.rs.html#1250-1275) of the `Result`!!

This is handy in a lot of situations, for example you can use `Iterator::flatten()` to sum all the values if `Ok()` but return `0.0` if `Err()`:

```
let x = all_payoffs.iter().flatten().sum::<f64>();
```

But here the compiler thinks that you are trying to sum vectors and that cannot be done, thus you get an error that says:

> the trait bound `f64: std::iter::Sum<&std::vec::Vec<f64>>` is not satisfied

That basically means: you cannot sum a bunch of `&Vec<f64>` and get a `f64` as a result.

The solution is right there in plain sight, use that `_v`:

```
Ok(v) => Ok(1.0 * v.iter().sum::<f64>()),
```

And now it works!